# com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am getting the below error while trying to insert some data into a Cassandra table from Spark.

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
        at com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:538)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:925)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
        at com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.SessionHolder.createSession(SessionHolder.java:137)
        at com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.SessionHolder.<init>(SessionHolder.java:83)
        at com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver$1.load(CassandraDriver.java:68)
        at com.github.adejanovski.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver$1.load(CassandraDriver.java:65)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
        ... 20 more
```

I am able to succesully execute the code first time, but when I execute the same code again, I am getting the aforementioned error.

Comment: Show us a [mcve] of your code please

Answer (score 0):

By default, packaged applications only contain your classes, not the libraries that you compiled with. Therefore, the spark drivers don't have any of the libraries you've used such as Cassandra connector.

You'll need to build an uber jar that contains all your dependent libraries when you are going to be using spark-submit. 
Using Maven or SBT can help you with that.

For Maven: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html